# String manipulation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a text file formatted like this:

```
1 50 20
2 23 22
3 45 90
4 44 49
.. .. ..
10 22 21
```

and I want to store the numbers into arrays. But I want to discard the counters and store 2nd column in an array and the third column in a different array. 
I read each line as a string and I'm not sure how can I just get the last two columns.

I used split first so:

```
string.split(" ");
```

But it doesn't work the way I want. I tried to use slice but since I have two digit numbers in counters, it won't work. Is there anyway to modify the split method? or a JS library with more string manipulation tools?

EDIT: So what doesn't work with split:

```
for (var i=7; i<linecount-1 ; i++){
            xcord.push(lines[i].split(" "));
```

If a line contains 1 50 20, if I use split I get 1,50,20. Question is how to get 50 in xcord array.

Comment: Please explain what about split doesn't work for you. Also, please edit your question to include your code attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each line, use `.split()` to get a temporary array of three elements, the item number and the other two numbers, so for the first line that'll be `[1,50,20]`. Then take the second and third elements from the temporary array and push them into your other arrays:

```
for (var line, i=7; i<linecount-1 ; i++){
    line = lines[i].split(" ");
    xcord.push(line[1]);
    ycord.push(line[2]);
}
```

(Your question doesn't currently show your second array, but I assume if the first is `xcord` then the other is `ycord`.)

Answer (score 2):

`.split(" ")` will return an array of the three values in each line.  You can reach into that array and get whichever of those three values you want.  The 2nd number in the line will be in the `[1]` element of the array.  The third number in the line will be in the `[2]` element of the array.  You can ignore the counter in the `[0]` element of the array.

You can do that like this:

```
for (var i=7; i<linecount-1 ; i++){
    var values = lines[i].split(" ");     // this will be an array like [1,50,20]
    xcord.push(values[1]);                // get the xcord from the array
    ycord.push(values[2]);                // get the ycord from the array
}
```